# Azure Custom Extension Policy

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

I am creating a custom policy to force all VM's that have an image from a certain resource group to join the domain by deploying an extension.

I have run into an issue with it not working and it keeps saying I do not have permissions even when I hard code the username and password into the variables.

```js
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "in": [
          "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachineScaleSets"
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageId",
        "contains": "resourceGroups/Templates"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
    "details": {
      "name": "Microsoft.PowerShell",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "existenceCondition": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
            "equals": "CustomScriptExtension"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
            "equals": "Microsoft.PowerShell"
          }
        ]
      },
      "deployment": {
        "properties": {
          "mode": "incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {
              "vmName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "location": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "variables": {
              "domainJoinUserName": "",
              "domainJoinUserPassword": "",
              "domainFQDN": "myDomain.com",
              "domainJoinOptions": 3
            },
            "resources": [
              {
                "comments": "Join domain - JsonADDomainExtension",
                "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
                "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
                "name": "[concat(trim(parameters('vmName')[copyIndex()]),'/joindomain')]",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "copy": {
                  "name": "vmDomainJoinCopy",
                  "count": "[length(parameters('vmName'))]"
                },
                "properties": {
                  "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                  "type": "JsonADDomainExtension",
                  "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3",
                  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                  "settings": {
                    "Name": "[variables('domainFQDN')]",
                    "User": "[variables('domainJoinUserName')]",
                    "Restart": "true",
                    "Options": "[variables('domainJoinOptions')]"
                  },
                  "protectedSettings": {
                    "Password": "[variables('domainJoinUserPassword')]"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very detailed Azure policy to join the VM with the Domain and it worked for me.Please check and see if it helps:

```js
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
      },
      {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageId",
            "in": "[parameters('listOfImageIdToInclude')]"
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "WindowsServer"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                "in": [
                  "2008-R2-SP1",
                  "2008-R2-SP1-smalldisk",
                  "2012-Datacenter",
                  "2012-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                  "2012-R2-Datacenter",
                  "2012-R2-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                  "2016-Datacenter",
                  "2016-Datacenter-Server-Core",
                  "2016-Datacenter-Server-Core-smalldisk",
                  "2016-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                  "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers",
                  "2016-Datacenter-with-RDSH"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "WindowsServerSemiAnnual"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                "in": [
                  "Datacenter-Core-1709-smalldisk",
                  "Datacenter-Core-1709-with-Containers-smalldisk",
                  "Datacenter-Core-1803-with-Containers-smalldisk"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsServerHPCPack"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "WindowsServerHPCPack"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftSQLServer"
              },
              {
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                    "like": "*-WS2016"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                    "like": "*-WS2016-BYOL"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                    "like": "*-WS2012R2"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                    "like": "*-WS2012R2-BYOL"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftRServer"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "MLServer-WS2016"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftVisualStudio"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "in": [
                  "VisualStudio",
                  "Windows"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftDynamicsAX"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "Dynamics"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                "equals": "Pre-Req-AX7-Onebox-U8"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "microsoft-ads"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "windows-data-science-vm"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "Windows-10"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
    "details": {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "roleDefinitionIds": [
        "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/"
      ],
      "existenceCondition": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/type",
            "equals": "JsonADDomainExtension"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/provisioningState",
            "equals": "Succeeded"
          }
        ]
      },
      "deployment": {
        "properties": {
          "mode": "incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {
              "ouPath": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "domainFQDN": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "vmName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "location": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "variables": {
              "domainJoinOptions": 131075
            },
            "resources": [
              {
                "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
                "comments": "Join domain - JsonADDomainExtension",
                "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/JsonADDomainExtension')]",
                "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "properties": {
                  "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                  "type": "JsonADDomainExtension",
                  "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3",
                  "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                  "settings": {
                    "Name": "[parameters('domainFQDN')]",
                    "User": "username",
                    "Restart": "true",
                    "Options": "[variables('domainJoinOptions')]",
                    "OUPath": "[parameters('ouPath')]"
                  },
                  "protectedSettings": {
                    "Password": "Password"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "outputs": {
              "policy": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "[concat('Enabled extension for VM', ': ', parameters('vmName'))]"
              }
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "vmName": {
              "value": "[field('name')]"
            },
            "location": {
              "value": "[field('location')]"
            },
            "ouPath": {
              "value": "[parameters('ouPath')]"
            },
            "domainFQDN": {
              "value": "[parameters('domainFQDN')]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure , you are passing correct user name and password.

Also alternatively  , you can refer this article for the same request.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2016/01/25/azure-arm-vm-domain-join-to-active-directory-domain-with-joindomain-extension/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.